# Manga where a group of high school students are transported to another world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

A group of high school students are brought to another world, but while training in the fields the mc “dies” protecting the girl who loves him. He is then teleported somewhere else that I forgot about. If that is not enough to find it this might help in one of the latest chapters from like 2-3 months ago one of his companions can use a gate type ability and she goes to collect supplies but she meets the mcs high school group and saves them.

Answer (score 3):

Could it be [**Arifureta: From Commonplace to World's Strongest**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arifureta:_From_Commonplace_to_World%27s_Strongest)? As noted on Wikipedia:

> High-schooler Hajime Nagumo is bullied by his classmate for his relationship with the class idol, Kaori. [...] During a dungeon raid, he is betrayed by one of his classmates and dropped to the bottom of the dungeon.

Hajime is presumed dead, but he goes on to gather a group of powerful monster girl companions and building his own strength. I admit I haven't read the manga or watched much of the anime myself, but there are definitely a few scenes where characters have teleportation / gating abilities of some kind, and more recent episodes have him re-uniting with some of his fellow students.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you are looking for [*Makikomarete Isekai Teni suru Yatsu wa, Taitei Cheat*](https://mangadex.org/title/22280/makikomarete-isekai-teni-suru-yatsu-wa-taitei-cheat) (*Those who were caught and transferred to another world*).

It starts with the MC being transported to another world with 4 friends.  It is determined he was brought along by accident, so they all go to an area that has monsters children can defeat to train.  A mud monster then absorbs him and is killed by one of his friends.  This teleports him elsewhere.

Advancing to the chapter from a few months ago, one of the companions the MC picked up went through a transfer gate and stumbled across the friends he left behind being attacked by creatures after a failed teleport attempt robbed them of most of their clothes and equipment.  She then defeats the creatures, gives them some potions and herbs, talks a bit, and then disappears.

The manga updated yesterday so there is at least one new chapter for you to enjoy.