# Manga with main character abandoned by goddess and classmates

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm looking for the name of manga where entire class is summoned by goddess but the main character has only paralysis, poison and sleep skills and is abandoned in a dungeon.

He uses those skills to kill monsters in a dungeon.

Definitely not Arifureta.
And ENTIRE school class is transported.

Comment: Class as in a school class? Or a DnD class? Summoning all Rogues!

Comment: Can you explain why *Arifureta* doesn't match what you're looking for? It looks like a perfect match for your description. If you can tell us what's different between *Arifureta* and the manga you're looking for, it might help us track down the right answer.

Comment: The main character is abandoned at the start in the summoning room where the goddess considers him incompetent with his set of skills and even his classmates do the same.

Comment: Is this it.? Hazure Waku no "Joutai Ijou Skill" de Saikyou ni Natta Ore ga Subete wo Juurin Suru made

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, I believe you are looking for *[I Became the Strongest With The Failure Frame](https://myanimelist.net/manga/122650/Hazurewaku_no_Joutai_Ijou_Skill_de_Saikyou_ni_Natta_Ore_ga_Subete_wo_Juurin_suru_made)* also known as *Hazure Waku no Joutai Ijou Skill de Saikyou ni Natta Ore ga Subete wo Juurin Suru made*

The manga starts out with a goddess addressing the class she just summoned and informs them that the main character is to be disposed of because he has the lowest aptitude and will bring down all the others.  A single student tries to stand up for him, but the goddess then knocks her out claiming his mere presences is already leading one of the highest aptitude members astray.  The rest of the class then insults and isolates him.  He is then teleported into a dungeon where he finds out his skills are poison, paralysis, and sleep.  He manages to paralyze the monster that initially attacks him, and then uses it to determine the limits of his abilities until it dies.

So while that entire description is just the first chapter, I feel that covers all the details from your question.

Answer (score 2):

Is this **Arifureta: From Commonplace to World's Strongest**?

> Hajime Nagumo and his entire high school class have been transported to another world, where all of them gain special powers for some as-yet-unspecified purpose. The problem is that Hajime's powers - transmutation and language ability - are much more utilitarian than combat-oriented.
>
> ... When a battle goes wrong, presumably because of a betrayal within the group, Hajime is left to die in an underground pit. —[ANN](https://www.animenewsnetwork.com/preview-guide/2019/summer/arifureta-from-commonplace-to-world-strongest/.148807)

Hajime has Poison Resistance and Paralysis Resistance according to the [wiki](https://arifureta.fandom.com/wiki/Hajime_Nagumo), “gained upon consuming Monster Meat.”

Comment: Also the answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/220625/manga-where-a-group-of-high-school-students-are-transported-to-another-world/220642?r=SearchResults#220642 where it is unaccepted